# IDE drag and drop for mobile development

Tags: ide, mobile, drag-and-drop

Somebody know a IDE for development for mobile like for blackberry, symbian, android, with Drag and drop, and if the answers is not why anybody has make it, or what it should it have to be great IDE drag and drop???

Answer (score 1):

here are some Android options:  [Easy way to build Android UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851882/easy-way-to-build-android-ui)

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of multi-device frameworks, if that's what you mean.

Unity3D is one, as well as PhoneGap (http://www.phonegap.com/)