# are there any GUI Tool for Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Are there any tools that can be used to design Android UI's (like the iPhone)?

I saw DroidDraw but it seemed a little outdated and wanted to know if there are any newer tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to build Android UI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851882/easy-way-to-build-android-ui)

Comment: It is but that was posted in 2009 and now we're in 2011 and newer tools maybe introduced.

Comment: Very true. Unfortunately the answers haven't changed (I'm kind of surprised, actually. After this length of time, I would have thought that at least a couple more tools would be mainstream!)

Comment: We have released a new tool named Designer4android which offers an alternative to the current XML based design method: [Designer4android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/designer4android.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Tool Link http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/designer4android.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

The standard Android-SDK Plugin for Eclipse brings a GUI-Designer with it. It's not perfect, but it's under active development.

Although, it should be the most up-to-date GUI-Designer for Android.

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK includes a WYSIWYG editor in the Eclipse ADT plugin.  I haven't used it (prefer working with the XML), but it's allegedly decent.

XML-focused GUI development resources:

- [Hello, Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)
- [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Comment: Got any documentation on how to create a UI with XML?

Comment: @Cocoa Dev - Just updated my answer with a couple links to some of the Android developer resources.