# Android GUI using Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin

I've been using XML to create my UI and I know this question may sound silly but it is not.

How do you create a UI using the Android plugin for Eclipse?

(Is there  a step by step tutorial somewhere or can someone give me step by step instructions)

Does the class name have to be the same as my view name?

Comment: Check this old post for other ideas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851882/easy-way-to-build-android-ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android plugin comes with handy visual editor where you can drag and drop views and widgets easily. And you don't have to name the xml files similar to your activity class because you will use `setContentView()` inside the activity to specify its view

Answer (score 3):

This may not quite be what you are looking for but I would check out DroidDraw.  Makes doing Android GUIs more friendly.  There is a tutorial at http://www.droiddraw.org/tutorial1.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's some (new!) overview documentation for the Eclipse plugin; see the "Canvas and Outline View" section in particular:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to create a rough sketch of whatever you're going to design first. Once you had a rough sketch/draft in your head,it becomes much easier to design the real thing.

Here are some UI guidelines : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

And if you're looking for tutorials :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maYFI5O6P-8&feature=relmfu