# Where is the Create Button form the UI editor?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Where is this button gone in the UI editor form ADT? Or what is the alternative?

[image: Create ...]

It was very useful to create new layouts for different screen configurations.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:** This button disappeared after updating to ADT 20.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is this button gone in the UI editor form ADT? Or what is the alternative?

If that is what I think it is, it is in the drop-down that, by default, is labeled "default":

[image]

When folded open, the drop-down looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for :) Thanks. It wasn't completely clear where it went but I guess this way can be clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer this [SO Question/Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851882/easy-way-to-build-android-ui) and followings links, that gives you the same or better UI development tool for different configuration.

- [Droid Draw](http://www.droiddraw.org/)
- [Android App Developers GUI Kits](http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/?mobify=0)
- [Android UI Utils](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/)
- [Simple UI](http://code.google.com/p/simpleui/)
- [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/)

I'm regularly using these tools for UI development for my Android Application, You can try this for your development.

**EDIT :** 
Sorry, I misunderstood the Question and the possible answer is,[image: Layout Editor]

You can get this button in **Android Common XML Editor** in top navigation bar, from there you can create alternative layout for different density.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP asked a very specific question about the UI editor in ADT revision 20.

Comment: I mean it's great that you provided the links but still, just saying that you probably misunderstood the question lol